# Google Deployment Manager Cloud Scheduler type

Tags: api, google-deployment-manager, google-cloud-scheduler

I see there's no schedule type provided by GCP. I'd like to know the steps to create a template, a composite-type or similar, to provide Cloud Scheduler type. I know Google already provides [an example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/community/dm_type_provider) about it.

If it's posible to do so by code It could make use of the [python client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/scheduler/index.html#) though it says in the documentation this library is not available, I could inline it in the code.

I cannot think of a way to authenticate against the google API to do such requests.

In short, my question is how can make Deployment Manager type for Cloud? I know it is sort of vague. Just want to know if it would be doable.

On the other hand, where can I find the official development for this 
GCP service?

For completenesss here's the related [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/369) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for this functionality and thought I should give an up to date answer on the topic.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9253778/dany-l for the feature request which led me to this answer.

It looks like this functionality is indeed provided, just that the documentation has yet to be updated to reflect it.

Here's the snippet from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123013878:

```
  - type: gcp-types/cloudscheduler-v1:projects.locations.jobs
    name: <YOUR_JOB_NAME_HERE>
    properties:
      parent: projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>/locations/<YOUR_REGION_HERE>
      name: <YOUR_JOB_NAME_HERE>
      description: <YOUR_JOB_DESCRIPTION_HERE>
      schedule: "0 2 * * *" # daily at 2 am
      timeZone: "Europe/Amsterdam"
      pubsubTarget:
        topicName: projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>/topics/<YOUR_EXPECTED_TOPIC_HERE>
        data: aGVsbG8hCg== # base64 encoded "hello!"
```

Comment: This issue was opened following a Partner support request to GCP. It only took them year and a half to solve. It is nice to have, but Terraform has proved to be more reliable than DM. It has better support, more coverage, flexibility and and it is more extended. I really liked DM and it's static approach, but we cannot work with this kind of support, it's unnaceptable :(

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Scheduler type is not supported yet according to [GCP's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types).

I am not aware of any official development for this GCP service other than the one I linked above. That being said, I will create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123013878) for your use case. Please add any additional that I have missed and you may use the same thread to communicate with the deployment manager team.

Answer (score 2):

You can use general `YAML` file with `deployment-manager`:

`config.yaml`:

```
resources:
  - name: <<YOUR_JOB_NAME>>
    type: gcp-types/cloudscheduler-v1:projects.locations.jobs # Cloud scheduler
    properties:
      parent: "projects/<<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>>/locations/<<YOUR_LOCATION_ID>>"
      description: "<<JOB_DESCRIPTION_OPTIONAL>>"
      schedule: "* */2 * * *" # accepts 'cron' format
      http_target:
        http_method: "GET"
        uri: "<<URI_TO_YOUR_FUNCTION>>" # trigger link in cloud functions
```

You even can add to create a `Pub/Sub` job and other with `deployment-manager` just add :

```
  - name: <<TOPIC_NAME>>
    type: pubsub.v1.topic
    properties:
      topic: <<TOPIC_NAME>>
  - name: <<NAME>>
    type: pubsub.v1.subscription
    properties:
      subscription: <<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>>
      topic: $(ref.<<TOPIC_NAME>>.name)
      ackDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

NOTE: to get <<YOUR_LOCATION_ID>> use `gcloud app describe`.

To deploy use:
`gcloud deployment-manager deployments create <<DEPLOYMENT_NAME>> --config=<<PATH_TO_YOUR_YAML_FILE>>`

To delete use:
`gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete <<DEPLOYMENT_NAME>> -q`

For more `properties` on `Cloud Scheduler` read the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#google.cloud.scheduler.v1.HttpTarget

Comment: I'm glad almost over two years after the feature-request GCP finally decided to implement this. We have since decided that GCP DM is not a reliable tool for Managing Deployments due to its very poor support. This was implemented and maintained in Terraform from day 1