# How to handle Google Cloud deployment manger Asynchronously

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Just like in AWS where you can have a SNS topic attached to trigger Cloud Formation and trigger a notification upon completion/failure.

Is there any way we can so something similar in Google Cloud Deployment Manager.

Comment: try to look this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216956/google-deployment-manager-cloud-scheduler-type) to get an idea to the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I researched for SNS feature to GCP public documentation, so far this feature is not available from GCP. however the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types is not updated yet.

Here's the snippet from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123013878:

```
- type: gcp-types/cloudscheduler-v1:projects.locations.jobs
    name: <YOUR_JOB_NAME_HERE>
    properties:
      parent: projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>/locations/<YOUR_REGION_HERE>
      name: <YOUR_JOB_NAME_HERE>
      description: <YOUR_JOB_DESCRIPTION_HERE>
      schedule: "0 2 * * *" # daily at 2 am
      timeZone: "Europe/Amsterdam"
      pubsubTarget:
        topicName: projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>/topics/<YOUR_EXPECTED_TOPIC_HERE>
        data: aGVsbG8hCg== # base64 encoded "hello!"
```